# Xcode6: Navigation Bar is overlapping textfield

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, autolayout, xcode6

I am using Xcode 6 and the tutorial I am following is using a version of Xcode 4 and so this is another issue that has turned up (I followed tutorial exactly).

So I created two initial scenes - a log-in and a sign-up scene, both of which have a username textfield at the top and then a password textfield directly below it. I then added buttons below these text fields.

Now I have a problem where my top-most UIelement, the username textfield, seems to be overlapped by the navigation bar, in that I can't see the username field anymore. 
I can see that the username text field exists when I look in outline, but have to double click on the navigation bar on top to see that field on the storyboard canvas.

I have a navigation controller set up. Embedded in it is a table view controller which links to the log in and sign up scenes - a show segue goes from the table view to the log in scene, and then another segue goes from the log in button to the sign up scene.

As well as the navigation bar blocking/overlapping my username text field, oddly there doesn't seem to be a Navigation item in outline for these two scenes- only the Button item and the text field items are there under the log in and sign up scene.

I thought that maybe I hadn't added the navigation controller properly and that it wasn't linked to these scenes, but when I run the program the navigation bar is there for all scenes, and anyway I can see it as a rectangular block at the top of my view (again for both scenes).

I need to make my Username text field visible, but also keep the navigation bar.

Is there any straightforward way to do this with interface builder or auto layout?

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I double clicked inside the navigation bar area where the textfield is hidden, and from there selected Drawing > View > Hidden.

The hidden checkbox was unchecked, so I checked it, and that made the username field visible inside navigation bar (strange!) and I then dragged it out of there and moved it to be underneath the navigation bar.

I would still like to know whether there might be a better way to have done this, I'm sure there is! But this is some kind of solution at least.

(I still cannot see navigation item in my scene outline)